# How to get review cycle duration information from gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

I'm trying to get some data on how long it takes for reviews to go through Gerrit on average.

Looking at some open source code, I see stuff like

```
reviewCreateTime = moment(mergedReviewsList[review].created);
reviewUpdateTime = moment(mergedReviewsList[review].updated);
interval = reviewUpdateTime.diff(reviewCreateTime, TIME_PERIOD_TYPE);
```

But with experimentation I don't think this logic is correct because adding a comment to a merged CR changes the updated timestamp.

I know this is possible because at the time of merge, Gerrit prints to the UI `Change has been successfully merged by XXX`.

I've been digging around in the mysql database but haven't found anything useful. I notice that changes that have been submitted have a submission_id, but I haven't found a table that stores submission information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bunch of digging around, I have come up with one rather ugly but workable solution.

There is a table change_messages

```
mysql> describe change_messages;
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| author_id             | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| written_on            | timestamp   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| message               | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| patchset_change_id    | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| patchset_patch_set_id | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| change_id             | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| uuid                  | varchar(40) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This basically stores stuff like `XXXX has been successfully merged by YYYY` and `XXXX has been successfully cherry-picked as YYYY by ZZZZ`.

You can then join this table with changes and datediff on change_messages.written_on and changes.created_on, e.g.

```
SELECT changes.change_id,
       created_on,
       written_on,
       Datediff(written_on, created_on) diff
FROM   change_messages
       INNER JOIN changes
               ON change_messages.change_id = changes.change_id
WHERE  message LIKE 'Change has been successfully merged by %'
ORDER  BY written_on;
```

Now this includes any time the CR was in draft mode. I'll edit this question if I get around to excluding that time.